# Oracle Age calculation from Date of birth and Today

Tags: oracle, datetime

I want to calculate the current Age from Date of Birth in my Oracle function.

What I am using is `(Today-Dob)/30/12`, but this is not accurate as some months have 31 days.

I need to get the correct age with the maximum precision. How can I do that?

Comment: take a look at this post, I think it has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819/oracle-equivalent-to-sql-server-sybase-datediff

Comment: Just some pedantic comments. When we say "age" it's probably a good idea to think more carefully about what the word *means*. Normally, when someone says "age", they *actually* mean "*how many birthday anniversaries have passed*". Scientifically, if we express two peoples' ages in years, we cannot compare them perfectly, regardless of precision, because their *actual age* will be different depending on when they were born - e.g. were they born in a leap year; how many leap seconds have been added/subtracted since then; were they born prior to September 1752? (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) It depends on what the question actually is - i.e. "which of these two people lived the longest" should be answered using a unit of time which doesn't change signfiicantly (e.g. days, or seconds). "Has this person passed their 18th birthday" is a different question, which I'd say is closer to what most people mean by "age".

Comment: Finally: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
SQL> select trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12) year,
  2         trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,dob),12)) month,
  3         trunc(sysdate-add_months(dob,trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12)*12+trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,dob),12)))) day
  4  from (Select to_date('15122000','DDMMYYYY') dob from dual);

      YEAR      MONTH        DAY
---------- ---------- ----------
         9          5         26

SQL>
```

Answer (score 25):

For business logic I usually find a decimal number (in years) is useful:

```
select months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),
                      to_date('15-Dec-2000','DD-MON-YYYY')
                     )/12
as age from dual;

       AGE
----------
9.48924731
```

Comment: AskTOM (Connor McDonald) says it fails in very few cases:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9531934000346471628

Recommends this one:
trunc((to_number(to_char(now,'YYYYMMDD'))- to_number(to_char(birth,'YYYYMMDD')))/10000)

Comment: Hi @RaúlMoreno, that simple formula actually results in much lower precision. That article is about calculating an age in integer years only. Connor himself says "This is a reasonable approximation, but still...an approximation". My algorithm is much more accurate, and does not suffer from the original problem expressed in that link (dividing number of days by 365 will often be incorrect, for hopefully obvious reasons).

Comment: Oh! sorry, I didn't noticed he wanted decimals. I wanted the age, real, in years, having into account leap years, etc. and this one is the only one which seems to get it right always (and it's not the one which divides by 365).

Comment: How do you convert the decimal-age back to a date(date of birth)? I have a question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504583/5576771

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT 
TRUNC((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(DOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/ 365.25) AS AGE_TODAY FROM DUAL;
```

This is easy and straight to the point.

Comment: best answer but need to +1 day

Answer (score 13):

Age (full years) of the Person:

```
SELECT
  TRUNC(months_between(sysdate, per.DATE_OF_BIRTH) / 12) AS "Age"
FROM PD_PERSONS per
```

Answer (score 5):

Or how about this?

```
with some_birthdays as
( 
    select date '1968-06-09' d from dual union all
    select date '1970-06-10' from dual union all
    select date '1972-06-11' from dual union all
    select date '1974-12-11' from dual union all
    select date '1976-09-17' from dual
)
select trunc(sysdate) today
, d birth_date
, floor(months_between(trunc(sysdate),d)/12) age
from some_birthdays;
```

Answer (score 3):

And an alternative without using any arithmetic and numbers (although there is nothing wrong with that):

```
SQL> with some_birthdays as
  2  ( select date '1968-06-09' d from dual union all
  3    select date '1970-06-10' from dual union all
  4    select date '1972-06-11' from dual union all
  5    select date '1974-12-11' from dual union all
  6    select date '1976-09-17' from dual
  7  )
  8  select trunc(sysdate) today
  9       , d birth_date
 10       , extract(year from numtoyminterval(months_between(trunc(sysdate),d),'month')) age
 11    from some_birthdays
 12  /

TODAY               BIRTH_DATE                 AGE
------------------- ------------------- ----------
10-06-2010 00:00:00 09-06-1968 00:00:00         42
10-06-2010 00:00:00 10-06-1970 00:00:00         40
10-06-2010 00:00:00 11-06-1972 00:00:00         37
10-06-2010 00:00:00 11-12-1974 00:00:00         35
10-06-2010 00:00:00 17-09-1976 00:00:00         33

5 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
SELECT ROUND((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('12-MAY-16'))/365.25, 5) AS AGE from DUAL;
```

You can configure `ROUND` to show as many decimal places as you wish.

Placing the date in decimal format like aforementioned helps with calculations of age groups, etc.

This is just a contrived example. In real world scenarios, you wouldn't be converting strings to date using `TO_DATE`.

However, if you have date of birth in date format, you can subtract two dates safely.

Comment: Given that it's an Age, might also be useful to consider using `FLOOR` instead of `ROUND` - If you're 29.99 years old, you'd still call yourself 29!

Answer (score 2):

This seems considerably easier than what anyone else has suggested

```
select sysdate-to_date('30-jul-1977') from dual;
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it's implicitly converting a string to a date, which may well go horribly wrong.

Comment: You should always include the date format in the call to TO_DATE(...) so you get correct/consistent results regardless of user/session preferences re: locale, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you want to have the age (number of years only, a fixed number) of someone born on `June 4, 1996`, execute this command :

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE - TO_DATE('04-06-1996')) / 365.25) AS AGE FROM DUAL;
```

#### Result : (Executed May 28, 2019)

```
       AGE
----------
        22
```

#### Explanation :

- `SYSDATE` : Get system's (OS) actual date.
- `TO_DATE('04-06-1996')` : Convert `VARCHAR` (string) birthdate into `DATE` (SQL type).
- `TO_NUMBER(...)` : Convert a date to `NUMBER` (SQL type)
- Devide per `365.25` : To have a [bissextile year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) every four years (4 * 0.25 = 1 more day).
- `Trunc(...)` : Retrieve the entire part only from a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL>select to_char(to_date('19-11-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),'yyyy') -  to_char(to_date('10-07-1986','dd-mm-yyyy'),'yyyy') year,
to_char(to_date('19-11-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),'mm') -  to_char(to_date('10-07-1986','dd-mm-yyyy'),'mm') month,
to_char(to_date('19-11-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd') -  to_char(to_date('10-07-1986','dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd') day from dual;

      YEAR      MONTH        DAY
---------- ---------- ----------
        31          4          9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD'), dob)/12)
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. This is very similar to many answers that are already here. Specifically, why is this a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below.

round(months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),date_of_birth)/12) as age,

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method,

`SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM APP_SUBMITTED_DATE)-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BIRTH_DATE) FROM SOME_TABLE;`

It will compare years and give age accordingly.
You can also use `SYSDATE` instead of `APP_SUBMITTED_DATE`.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Select  trunc(to_number(sysdate - to_date(dob) /365.25)) as Age from desingh

### AGE

26
25
31

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select (extract(year from current_date)-extract(year from Date_of_birth)) as Age from table_name;`

age=current_year - birth_year;
```

> extract(year/month/date from date) //oracle function for extracting values from date

Answer (score -4):

select (SYSDATE-DOB)/365 "Age" from dual