# Checking if beneficiary is adult (more than 18 year) when inserting

Tags: oracle

In "beneficiary" table I have "birthDate" column, when beneficiary registered, i want check, if it is not adult (no more than 18 year), I want disallow register

For example today is "2017-04-05" and if beneficiary tries insert birth date "1999-04-06", I want disallow insert. if birth date is "1999-04-05" or earlier, insert must happen.

After searched found trigger are for this? I tried several ways but not realized how to add this restriction to my table.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015431/oracle-age-calculation-from-date-of-birth-and-today

Comment: Please post your attempts to help people to improve your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

(If you never update birthDate column, then you can remove this piece: `OR UPDATE` and recreate trigger )

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON beneficiary
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.birthDate >  add_months(sysdate , -12*18)  then
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Underage user');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server databases, you can use the DATEDIFF function in your trigger:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthDate, SYSDATE) >= 18
```

In Oracle databases, you can use the MONTHS_BETWEEN function:

```
months_between(SYSDATE, birthDate)/12 >= 18
```

Comment: whoops no its a SQL Server function. there's a similar approach in oracle, give me a second to find it and ill add it to my answer