# Convert decimal year to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-format, oracle12c

I have dates in a table that are [stored as decimal years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time). An example is `2003.024658` which translates to `January 9, 2003`.
**I would like to convert the decimal years to Oracle's date format.**

---

I've found someone who's done this in Excel: [Decimal year to date formula?](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/569750-decimal-year-date-formula.html)

```
 =DATE(INT(B1),1,MOD(B1,1)*(DATE(INT(B1)+1,1,1)-DATE(INT(B1),1,1)))
```

However, I can't quite figure out how to convert the logic to Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind conversion of `2003.024658` to `January 9, 2003` ?

Comment: `SELECT TO_DATE ('31-DEC-2002') + (0.024658 * 365) FROM DUAL` gives output `09-Jan-2003`.

Comment: Not needed. If it has helped you, that's enough.

Comment: Do please "accept" that answer so that others who want an answer know there is one, or those seeking to provide an answer don't get disappointed.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yeah, the system makes me wait 2 days before accepting my own answer.

Comment: If you want the answer to be exact, it would depend on exactly how the decimal portion (`0.024658`) was originally calculated by whoever recorded the values in the first place - e.g. on a simple 365 days/year, or some average estimate like 365.24, or perhaps some other scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start from the assumption that the decimal portion was calculated according to the *number of days in the given year* (i.e. 365 or 366 depending on whether it was a leap year), you could do something like this:

```
with
 q1 as (select 2003.024658 d from dual)
,q2 as (select d
              ,mod(d,1) as decimal_portion
              ,to_date(to_char(d,'0000')||'0101','YYYYMMDD')
               as jan01
        from q1)
,q3 as (select q2.*
              ,add_months(jan01,12)-jan01 as days_in_year
        from q2)
select d
      ,decimal_portion * days_in_year as days
      ,jan01 + (decimal_portion * days_in_year) as result
from   q3;

d: 2003.024658
days: 9.00017
result: 10-JAN-2003 12:00am
```