# List Users Over a Certain Age

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to list all the users who are above the age of 13 and have downloaded an app in the category `"Social"`. With the users date of births in ascending order.

Below I attempted to convert users date of births into an int number and use that to only display users over "13" but to no avail.

---

My code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(u."Username" AS varchar2(20)) AS "Username",
    CAST(u."FirstName" AS varchar2(15)) AS "FirstName",
    CAST(u."LastName" AS varchar2(15)) AS "LastName",
    TRUNC((sysdate - u."DateOfBirth")/365.25) AS "DateOfBirth" 
FROM BR_USER u, BR_APPCATEGORY ap
WHERE ap."CategoryName" = 'Social' AND "DateOfBirth" > '13'
ORDER BY "DateOfBirth" ASC;
```

---

The error I receive :

```
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE "BR_USER"(
     "UserId" NUMBER(6,0),
     "Username" VARCHAR2(35) CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_USERNAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "FirstName" VARCHAR2(30),
     "LastName" VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "Email" VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "Gender" VARCHAR2(3),
     "JoinDate" DATE CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_JOINDATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "DateOfBirth" DATE CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_DOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "CountryId" NUMBER(3,0),
     CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_EMAIL_CORRECT" CHECK ("Email" like '%@%'),
     CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE" UNIQUE("Email"),
     CONSTRAINT "BR_USER_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("UserId") ENABLE
     )
/
CREATE TABLE "BR_APPCATEGORY"(
     "AppCategoryId" NUMBER(2,0),
     "CategoryName" VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT "BR_APPCATEGORY_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "Description" VARCHAR2(100),
     CONSTRAINT "BR_APPCATEGORY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("AppCategoryId") ENABLE
)
/
```

Comment: DateOfBirth is not the same thing as Age.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Age calculation from Date of birth and Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015431/oracle-age-calculation-from-date-of-birth-and-today)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well I assumed my logic might be wrong and I could list users over 13 years old just using their date of birth but I didn't know how

Comment: What is the data-type of column _DateOfBirth_ ? And why do you need to `CAST` the columns _Username_, _FirstName_ and _LastName_ ?

Comment: @Abra I had to cast the columns to make their character limits smaller so the columns would fit on screen, I was asked specifically not to change or alter the original sql script. Also I've included an image of how the table was created in my post. an example of a d.o.b : ```to_date('19-Apr-19','DD-MON-RR')```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. Instead, please add them to your question as text - this makes it easier for people to reproduce your problem and find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Your query involves two database tables but it does not contain any kind of join. The tables `BR_USER` and `BR_APPCATEGORY` need to be somehow related. According to what you posted, I see no relation between them.

Comment: @Abra I'm just initially trying to figure out how to list users above the age of 13 in my single BR_USER table. I'm not looking to join the tables as of yet.

Comment: @LukStorms it gives me an error ```ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "age": invalid identifier```

Comment: @LukStorms yup I think so

Comment: @UnboundPhantom `cast` is not the way to take a substring.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I'm not trying to take a substring, I'm trying to make columns smaller so they fit on screen while still displaying all the rows correctly.

Comment: @UnboundPhantom what screen? Most applications adjust result grids automatically. SQL\*Plus has column formatting commands. Using `cast` to avoid specifying a format like `col username format a20 trunc` just seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the linked answer in Robert Harvey's first comment to your question, plus the `CREATE TABLE` statement you provided, plus your clarification that at this stage you only want users over 13 years of age, the following SQL should provide you the results you desire.

```sql
SELECT substr(u."Username", 1, 20) AS "Username"
      ,substr(u."FirstName", 1, 15) AS "FirstName"
      ,substr(u."LastName", 1, 15) AS "LastName"
      ,TRUNC(u."DateOfBirth") AS "DateOfBirth"
 FROM BR_USER u
WHERE months_between(TRUNC(sysdate), u."DateOfBirth") / 12 > 13
ORDER BY u."DateOfBirth"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use direct date comparisons:

```
WHERE "DateOfBirth" < sysdate - interval '13' year
```

To be honest, this could cause a problem in leap years on Feb 29th.  For some reason, Oracle allows this rare bug.  So, `add_months()` is recommended:

```
WHERE "DateOfBirth" < add_months(sysdate, -13 * 12)
```

Note that both of these expressions are index-friendly, meaning that they can take advantage of an index on `"DateOfBirth"`, if one is available and the optimizer thinks that is a good idea.

A function such as `months_between()` generally prevents an index from being used, which is why these solutions are preferable.

Comment: You are so competent at what you do.

Comment: Regarding the buggy treatment of February, I believe this is mandated by ANSI.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson . . . If you have a reference I would appreciate it.  I would note that Postgres, MySQL, and SQL Server (at least) all calculate one year before 2020-02-29 as 2019-02-28 (although the syntax varies among the databases).  Subtracting or adding a year or month does not ever result in an error in these (and other) databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was a comment by Tom Kyte on [this Oracle-WTF blog post](https://oracle-wtf.blogspot.com/2006/02/stop-press-oracle-granted-license-to.html). (There seems to be something wrong with the Blogger code at the moment and some Twitter-related resource takes a minute to time out, so you have to wait a bit for the comments to appear, sorry.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff aha, page is slow in https. [Faster link here](http://oracle-wtf.blogspot.com/2006/02/stop-press-oracle-granted-license-to.html).