# How to calculate age using DOB in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How to calculate age using DOB in oracle sql?
Column name:  GET_DOB
Table name: J ,
DOB Date format: 8/10/2022

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015431/oracle-age-calculation-from-date-of-birth-and-today#:~:text=SELECT%20TRUNC((SYSDATE%20%2D%20TO_DATE,and%20straight%20to%20the%20point.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DOB column is a date you could do the following:

```sql
SELECT a.*, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
FROM   your_table a
```

otherwise you need to cast string to date:

```
SELECT a.*, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) / 12) age
FROM   your_table a
```

In case you want to have age as a column (bear in mind that age changes with time):

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_view
AS
  SELECT a.*,
         TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
  FROM   your_table a;
```

Use this SQL fiddle for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8e1b/1

Comment: Will this result be in years or months?

Comment: @JtR in full years

Comment: It didn’t work as it is in another select statement. Would the syntax be different for making it a sub query?

Comment: The overall logic will be the same. Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve please?

Comment: Yes I want this to show up as a column along with multiple other colums in the result. For example: select abc, k. Name, k. Gender, k. DOB, k. Age, k. City

Comment: Since age always changes I would recommend you create a view with this calculated `AGE` column. I have just edited my post so you can see it there.

Comment: Since this is in another query, should I start with a bracket” ( “ ?

Comment: Once you create a view you can explicitly query it as you do with tables: `select * from your_view`;

Comment: So this is how the whole thing will look like: select abc, k. Name, k. Gender, k. DOB, k. Age, CREATE VIEW your_view
AS
  SELECT a.*,
         TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
  FROM   your_table a;  k. City ?

Comment: Not exactly. See the SQLFiddle I attached to my answer. `View` is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement. It would help you have `age` calculated on the fly each time you query the view.
I also edited my answer to include the rest of the columns into the result set.

Comment: Can you write this in my query that I wrote? select abc, k. Name, k. Gender, k. DOB, k. Age, k. City

Comment: select 
   k.City, 
   k.Name, 
   k.Gender, 
   k.DOB, 
   TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, k.DOB) / 12) Age
FROM your_table k;

Comment: So I am not creating a view anymore?

Comment: In case you decide to create a view:
`create view your_view as select k.City, k.Name, k.Gender, k.DOB, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, k.DOB) / 12) Age from your_table k;`
Then query your view:
`select * from your_view;`